Python Turtle : Handling two successive screens for two successive event-listener driven game Functions
I'm new to Python and trying out Turtle through Tutorials. This question turned out to be verbose, my bad.
I have designed 2 Games handled by 2 Functions (in a separate module) which are called from MAIN:

F1 : Plays an Etch a Sketch Game where user inputs are used to move
the Turtle to draw
F2 : Plays a Turtle Race where 5 Turtles (I have
used a list to handle 5 Objects) move at randomized paces to see who
wins.

The ISSUE :

The Games work fine individually on the first iteration but I have a loop in MAIN where user can choose games multiple times. On the second iteration, the screen pops up but I don't see the Turtles and when I click I get Turtle Terminator error.
I have initialized a create_screen() method in a separate config.py file which I import in each FN to create a screen. I then use exitonclick() to end the display. Mainloop() didn't work here. (Should I use Global - Just wanted to see how to make it work WITHOUT Global)
I need FN1 to stop listening and the ask user if he wants FN2, then move to FN2 and I can't seem to get that done without exitonclick() on FN1.  How can I keep the screen alive, displayed, ready for FN2 ? It's the only reason I am using Screen on config file and creating with FNs. I'm sure there is a way, I just don't know it yet.

Solutions I have checked indicate the Turtle._RUNNING = True Flag which can be changed, but what is a better way to implement this without changing a Class Variable (or using Global) ? If someone can point me to the some sources (other than TURTLE DOCS) for Screen and Event Listeners to solve this, I'll do the learning myself !
Code Skeleton : I'm loading config.py into FN Module and the Game Functions from MAIN
# Module : config.py

from turtle import Turtle, Screen

squad = []
for i in range(0, 5):  # List of Turtle Objects available to all Modules
    raphael = Turtle()
    raphael.speed(0)
    squad.append(raphael)

def create_screen():
    """Creates and Returns a screen Object"""
    screen = Screen()
    screen.screensize(400, 400)
    screen.colormode(255)
    return screen

# Module : gamefunction.py

from config import squad, create_screen

def etch_sketch_game():
    """Plays the Etch a Sketch Game"""

    screen_fn = create_screen()

    def forwards():  # Other FNs designed but not included for this Question
        squad[0].fd(30)

    screen_fn.listen()
    screen_fn.onkey(key="w", fun=forwards)
    screen_fn.exitonclick()


def turtle_race(): # Only adde
    """Plays the Turtle Race Game"""

    screen_fn = create_screen()

    squad[0].setpos(-200, 30)
    squad[1].setpos(-200, 20)
    squad[2].setpos(-200, 0)
    squad[3].setpos(-200, -20)
    squad[4].setpos(-200, -30)

    def forwards():  # Other FNs designed but not included for this Question
        squad[0].fd(30)

    screen_fn.onkey(key="w", fun=forwards)
    screen.exitonclick()


Move exitonclick outside of the game-specific logic. You can keep one screen open and clear/reset it when the user switches games. Once you exit, turtle is done and can't be touched again. You can hack around it with _RUNNING = False, but this is undocumented and so your program can break at any point if it's run on an incompatible version of Python that abruptly removes this internal property.

Does this answer your question? Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick()

I've checked the post above already and no it doesn't answer my usecase where two listener based games are happening succesively. As @ggorlen said, I did try to keep the screen.exitonclick() outside and only at the end, but I am failing to get the screen to work fine when switching between the two games. How do I stop Game 1 from listening and proceed to Game 2 which has different lister events setup ? Is there a way I can capture an input like "x" (when user wants to stop drawing) and return it from the function to main loop ?

Could you share your attempt at moving exitonclick() outside the functions? You can remove or replace key bindings when a game ends.

@ggorlen I have added a comment on your answer below.

Your question is somewhat answered by Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick() in that as of CPython 3.12, the only way to use exitonclick() more than once is to mess with an internal variable _RUNNING. If you want to work within turtle's public API, short of running subprocesses, you're sort of stuck with one screen for your whole application. This means that you'll need to move the exitonclick() outside each game, to be a one-time call. All games will reuse the same screen.
With that in mind, Screen() is basically a singleton factory getter for the one screen turtle gives you, so your create_screen is a bit misleadingly named.
In your application, it seems you want to have the user click to return to the main menu, so we'll use a normal click handler for that rather than exitonclick(). That handler is responsible for clearing out state from the previous game and prompting the user for the next game. For simplicity's sake, I'm using textinput, but in a fancier app this would probably be a clickable turtle button for better UX. Consider this a proof of concept which will require adaptation to your use case.
I've also moved everything into one file, but you can move it back out to multiple files easily if you want.
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def new_game():
    """Resets state and lets the user choose a new game"""
    screen.onkey(key="w", fun=None)
    screen.onkey(key="a", fun=None)
    screen.onkey(key="d", fun=None)

    for t in turtles:
        t.reset()
        t.hideturtle()
        t.penup()

    while True:
        game = screen.textinput(
            "Choose game",
            "Choose game ('sketch', 'race' or 'quit'):"
        )

        if not game:
            continue
        elif game.lower().strip() in ("sketch", "race"):
            break
        elif game.lower().strip() == "quit":
            return screen.bye()

    if game == "sketch":
        etch_sketch_game()
    else:
        turtle_race()


def etch_sketch_game():
    """Runs an etch a sketch game"""
    screen.onkey(key="w", fun=lambda: t.forward(30))
    screen.onkey(key="a", fun=lambda: t.left(30))
    screen.onkey(key="d", fun=lambda: t.right(30))
    screen.listen()
    t = turtles[0]
    t.showturtle()
    t.pendown()


def turtle_race():
    """Runs a turtle race game"""
    def forward():
        turtles[0].forward(30)

    screen.onkey(key="w", fun=forward)
    screen.listen()
    turtles[0].setpos(-200, 30)
    turtles[1].setpos(-200, 20)
    turtles[2].setpos(-200, 0)
    turtles[3].setpos(-200, -20)
    turtles[4].setpos(-200, -30)

    for t in turtles:
        t.showturtle()
        t.pendown()


def initialize():
    """Performs one-time setup for entire application"""
    for i in range(5):
        t = Turtle()
        t.speed(0)
        t.hideturtle()
        turtles.append(t)

    screen.screensize(400, 400)
    screen.colormode(255)
    screen.onclick(lambda *_: new_game())
    new_game()
    screen.mainloop()


# global state; can encapsulate in a module or class as you see fit
turtles = []
screen = Screen()
initialize()

By the way, it's good that you've allocated turtles up front. There's currently no real way to get rid of turtles once they're created, so keeping them in a global object pool is the best approach.
As another aside, you may not actually need any global state of your own since turtle manages all of the state used in the above program. screen = Screen() can be done per file. Screen().turtles() can be used in place of the turtles = [] list. This might allow you to remove the config file.
See this answer if you want real-time turtle control, avoiding those pesky keyboard retriggers.

Thanks a lot for working this out. However, I am still unsure of lambdas so I am reading through ref-documentation now before implementing this. I understand the logic, and also how initilaize() kicks it off, then new_game() is the repeatable FN to get each game going. However, I don't see how you return from etch_sketch_game FN or turtle_race FN after it has been triggered the first time. How will the user exit the FN ? I believe it will be the new_game() again but then, should we bind it to a keyboard key within each game FN ? Please point that out in case I missed it in your code.

The user exits each game back to the menu by clicking the screen, same behavior as exitonclick but without exiting turtle: screen.onclick(lambda *_: new_game()).

Ah okay. Alright, that's great then, it should solve my problem. I'll take a little time to read the docs and then implement your logic, and mark your answer as Accepted post that. Thanks a lot !

One qq : I know lambda _ is supposed to be the ignored variable (the underscore). Is *_ signifying packing a FN name ? I know this sounds like a newbie question but I am. I'm trying to look it up meanwhile.

*_ means ignore the parameters (_ is by convention). Clicks pass x/y coordinates into the callback but we don't care about them in this app. You can write it the same way by adding 2 parameters new_game(_x, _y) and skipping the lambda, but I prefer a wrapper because x, y are irrelevant to starting a new game and shouldn't be part of the function contract.

Thanks a tonne, it works and accomplishes the ask. I still need to read up on timer and understand the ontimer() purpose here, but I get the rest of the code. I guess the ontimer() without any time-unit parameter means the FN within the brackets is called immediately, but ontimer() and oncllick() seems to be doing the same thing. I'll look it up, but it totally works, thanks.

ontimer says run the code asynchronously after the call stack clears. It turns out not to be necessary here, but sometimes it's useful to ensure mainloop() is reached.

I see that if the ontimer() is not included, the first text input doesn't get triggered automatically at the start, and instead only when Screen Click happens, rest works the same. I also wanted to remove the infinite while, and make it if "sketch" : sketch() elif "race" : race() else screen.bye() and that works the same (as far as I have tested till now). I've restructrured into my own FNs but I've used the same logic as in yours to handle screen inputs, which I really needed, thanks

If you remove ontimer(), that's fine, but don't remove the call to new_game() if you want the initial prompt. See my updated code. The infinite while is to re-prompt the user for input if they give a bad response. I think it's good UX, but you can do whatever you need for your app-specific needs. This is just an example POC intended to be modified. The main focus is on the overall design, not specific arbitrary decisions I made as part of the example, like input. You can trigger scene transitions with buttons, clicks, or any other predicate (like a turtle reaching a goal in a race).

if "sketch" : sketch() elif "race" : race() else screen.bye() won't work because you need to compare if game == "sketch", etc. if "sketch": is always true.

Yes, I just tried to put up pseudocode there, I did mean if game == "sketch": sketch() and the same for the rest, otherwise it won't work. Regarding the bad response handling, yes I agree, that's better UX. I'll try to do something without a while True for that.
